# User friendly URL through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My url looks like -
`http://localhost/user_notes/?id=1234`.
I want to be turn it into user friendly url like
`http://localhost/user_notes/1234`

My `.htaccess` file looks like -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /user_notes/?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

The problem is with `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /user_notes/?id=$1`

For more info see my [directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQFRG.png)

**Note :** In my directory structure there is also a public folder. But I can access files without including `public` in URL through htaccess file (line 3).

Answer (score 0):

Could you please place these rules at top of your htaccess file(I hope there are NO redirect rules for https in your htaccess file). Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteRule ^(user_notes)/(.*)/?$ $1/?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: should I replace my htaccess content with yours ?

Comment: @Abhishekkamal, yes please try it once and let me know quickly as it's late night here :)

Comment: I have done but nothing new is happening.

Comment: @Abhishekkamal, do you any other rules also apart from shown ones?

Comment: @Abhishekkamal, then how your non existing pages or directories going to get server in backend? Is it by index.php file?

Comment: yes index.php file which is main index file stored in `public` folder as '/user_notes/public/index.php'

Comment: In my .htaccess file (line 3) is used for accessing the files without including `public` in URL and line 4 is used for accessing files without `.php` extension

Comment: both line 3 & line 4 are working fine but line 5 is not working that's why I am here

Comment: Thanks for here. I am going to sleep. In morning I will post a new question (with more info) and give you the link here.

Comment: @Abhishekkamal, hey is it same like your other question? Please confirm once.